# Getting metadata from image using Sanselan in android(Titanium Appcelerator)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to get metadata of image using Sanselan library. In native android I am able to write metadata. But making module for android and using it in Titanium Appcelerator it gives me warning for classes used in Sanselan(e.g. -

```
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;).....
Could not find class 'java.awt.Dimension', referenced from method org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.jpeg.JpegImageParser.getImageSize)
```

I get these warning in native android also but

```
 IImageMetadata metadata = Sanselan.getMetadata(file);
```

returns me object of metadata and I can copy metadata to image file where as in Titanium appcelerator metadata object is simply returns null.

So anyone used this library in Titanium Appcelerator as android module? or can any one suggest what is going wrong here?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Titanium expert. Anyway, it looks like you are using the plain java sanselan library. Is that correct? The package "java.awt" is not part of the Android SDK. That's the reason why "java.awt.Dimension" cannot be found.

There is an android port of sanselan in which such classes have been excluded. See https://code.google.com/p/sanselanandroid/

I just cloned a gradlefied version of that project to GitHub. You can find a binary in the "releases" section. See https://github.com/SebastianEngel/sanselanandroid/

Maybe that can help you.